# git ls-files: howto identify new files (added, not committed)?

Tags: git

After I called `git add <file>` the command `git status` will show me something like:

```
...
new file:    <file>
```

Somehow I can't manage it to get the same information by using `ls-files`, it (`ls-files -tc` in this case) will show me:

```
H <commited file>
H <other commited file>
H <file>
```

There seems no commandline switch to exist for new files. The file is reported as cached, which is ok, but how do I find out that it is not committed at this time?

Is this possible with `ls-files` or some similar command (where I do not have to parse a lot of output like in the case of `git status`)?

Answer (score 129, accepted):

You want to use `git diff --cached`.  With `--name-only` it'll list all the files you've changed in the index relative to HEAD.  With `--name-status` you can get the status symbol too, with `--diff-filter` you can specify which set of files you want to show ('A' for newly added files, for instance).  Use `-M` to turn on move detection and `-C` for copy detection if you want them.

For the strictest reading of what you wrote, `git diff --cached --name-only --diff-filter=A` will list all the files you've added since HEAD which don't exist in HEAD.

Comment: FYI: Your "strictest reading" didn't include the `--cached` flag.

Comment: For your copying pleasure: `git diff --cached --name-only`

Comment: No we want to use `ls-files`, that's why we came here

Answer (score 64):

**Clarification:** This is a way to show the files that I *intend* to add. This is not what the OP was looking for, but I'll leave this post in case it's useful to others.

This seems to show only the files that I have added *[to my working copy, not the index]* but aren't matched by my standard ignore patterns:

```
 $ git ls-files --others --exclude-standard
```

Without `--exclude-standard`, it also shows files that are ignored when I run `git status`.

Comment: A problem is a file that matches a rule in the `.gitignore` file and was added with `git add -f` ... it will not be shown with `--exclude-standard`. I am wondering where `git status` gets its informations from

Comment: Wait, I might have messed this up -- do you want the files you still need to add, or are you looking for newly added files that are already in the index?

Comment: I am looking for added files that are in the index but not commited yet

Comment: Ah, then I think Andrew's answer is the better one. Will edit mine to clarify this.

Comment: "Added" can be interpreted as being added to the filesystem or added to git, so I am upvoting this answer, not because it answers the OP's original intention, but because someone could have used the OPs original terms looking for an answer with your intention, which is exactly what I did. Thank you, @MikeSeplowitz.

Answer (score 5):

Simple way to get all new, modified and removed files:

```
git ls-files --others --modified --deleted --exclude-standard
```

Refer to official documentation: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-files

Use "--others" if you wish to see new/untracked files

Use "--modified" if you wish to see modified files

Use "--deleted" if you wish to see deleted files

--exclude-standard will exclude the files specified in .gitignore

Answer (score 4):

I would like to see all the added and modified files, so the merge of
`git diff --cached --name-only`
+
`git ls-files --modified --deleted`
but without `[1]+ Stopped ...` in between.

When I use `git diff --cached --name-only && git ls-files --modified --deleted` I receive:

```
content/blog/2020/05/artificial-intellect.json
content/blog/2020/05/artificial-intellect.pug

[1]+  Stopped                 git diff --cached --name-only
content/index.json
index.php
```

Answer (score 0):

But if you commited and pushed like me, you can

`git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r HEAD | xargs zip archive.zip`

Comment: What does this command do? Does this creates a zip of files changed and that are deleted?

Comment: create zip file with changed files