# git: list new files only

Tags: git, status

When I do a `git status` I get a list of files prefixed with `new file:` . How can I get only this list? I want to process this files in a simple loop in a little shell script.

Comment: Have you tried 'grep'? `git status | grep new file`.

Comment: Yes, but that does not get me the plain file names.

Comment: I would rather use `git ls-files --others --exclude-standard` (http://stackoverflow.com/a/2299448/6309)

Comment: Related [Git: list only “untracked” files (also, custom commands)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3801321/3383878)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I would use something like `git status --porcelain | grep "^A" | cut -c 4-`

Comment: It's years later, but this no longer works for me (the output of `git status` has likely changed). **EDIT:** Bah. Hadn't added/committed it. Stands the test of time!

Comment: To get both unstaged (untracked) and staged new files: `git status --porcelain | grep '^A\|^??' | cut -c 4-`

Answer (score 111):

**The commands below no longer give the expected results, I may originally also have made some mistakes. Please double-check your output and the options you are using. Nevertheless: The basic tenet of using diff-filter should still hold true.**

Don't use grep to parse git output. Git almost certainly has the things you are looking for built-in (except if you are going for really advanced stuff).
You can use `git diff` to show the changes. `--name-only` shows only the filenames. `--diff-filter=A` lists only the added files.
If you want to see new files you have already added to the index use `--cached`, otherwise omit it. To see both diff to `HEAD`.
The commands look like this:

```
git diff --name-only --diff-filter=A --cached # All new files in the index  
git diff --name-only --diff-filter=A          # All files that are not staged  
git diff --name-only --diff-filter=A HEAD     # All new files not yet committed
```

Comment: diff-filter is actually the way to go :)

Comment: It's quite unfortunate that the OP doesn't accept this answer, as in my humble opinion, you're completely right. :)

Comment: Is there something similar for "All files since the branch was created"?

Comment: @MattR there is. The diff command takes two commit hashes as arguments. So presumably you want to diff from your current HEAD (1st arg). To find the the commit where your current HEAD and another branch diverge use `merge-base` like so: `git merge-base HEAD other-branch`
Put the result into the original diff command: `git diff --name-only --diff-filter=A HEAD "$(git merge-base HEAD other-branch)"`

Comment: The first of the three commands is correct. The second doesn't make much sense, since a file is only marked as "new" when it has been staged. The third is wrong, as it doesn't even list files that are marked as "new" in the index.

Comment: Am I missing something or is it juste completely wrong, as @PeterJohnAcklam said ?

Comment: @agemO, this used to work. I agree though, that this is complete BS now. (I added a note to the answer)

Comment: I don't know why someone claims that _"The third is wrong, as it doesn't even list files that are marked as "new" in the index"_, but the third command is working perfectly for me as of today, and it answers the exact question that OP asked for -- how to get the pure list of the `new file:` of the `git status` output, which is what I came here for.

Answer (score 46):

You can use **git status --short** to get the list of files.

Comment: This should not be overlooked.

Comment: The OP asked for how to get the pure list of the `new file:` of the `git status` output, just get him _"the plain file names"_, but this one has an extra status leading character.

Comment: Fantastic! Just what I wanted! git ls-files --others wasn't working for me. With git status --short, I could just grep for "^??". Thanks!

Comment: To get rid of untracked files from the output, instead of grepping for `^??`, try using `git status --short --untracked-files=no`, or even more briefly, `git status -suno`

Answer (score 38):

Instead of parsing the output of "git status", it is probably more elegant to use

```
git ls-files -o  --exclude-standard
```

As with `git status`, `ls-files` will produce output relative to your currrent working directory.

You may wish to include the `--full-name` option:

```
git ls-files -o  --exclude-standard --full-name
```

Comment: OP asked to list new files and this answer doesn't required any other programs to pipe the output to. I found on mac git diff didn't work with the filters as expected while this did :)

Comment: This is clearly the winner. It works on new directories containing all new files.

Comment: However, note that this doesn't work from subdirectories.

I ended up using `git diff` to make my script work from every directory in the repository:

`$ git diff --name-only --diff-filter=A HEAD`

Comment: @AndreasSiegel, this is by design as it is generally more helpful to follow the behaviour of the ls-files command. Since the command follows the general convention of accepting qualifying arguments, a better solution for your alias would be to amend the alias as follows:
<code>git ls-files -o  --exclude-standard --full-name -- `git rev-parse --show-toplevel`</code>

Comment: @AndreasSiegel, this is by design as it is generally more helpful to follow the behaviour of the ls-files command. Since the command follows the general convention of accepting qualifying arguments, a better solution for your alias would be to amend the alias as follows:
`git ls-files -o  --exclude-standard --full-name -- ``git rev-parse --show-toplevel```

Comment: As of git version 2.39.2, this doesn't include any of the "new file"s output by `git status`. It lists only untracked new files.

Answer (score 1):

List of new files or to get files to be added to git, can be got using git status and grep command like `git status -s | grep ??`

```
root@user-ubuntu:~/project-repo-directory# git status -s | grep ??
 ?? src/.../file1.js
 ?? src/.../file2.js
 ?? src/.../file3.js
 ....
```

Answer (score 0):

```
git status | grep "new file:" | cut -c 14-

git status | grep "modified:" | cut -c 14-
```

Answer (score 0):

To list All new files that is not added before to git project, you  can use this command

> **`git ls-files -o`**

The -o option is shorthand for --others

see this gif image
[image: list new files in git]