# Git list of staged files

Tags: git, git-diff, git-status, git-stage

I staged a lot of files using `git add`, and now I want to see all the files I have staged, without *untracked* files or *changed, but unstaged* files.

How do I do that? When using `git diff --cached` I can see the changes of what I just staged. So then I tried using `git status --cached`, but that `--cached` unfortunately doesn't work on `git status`.

Comment: simply typing `git status` gives you a list of staged files, a list of modified yet unstaged files, and a list of untracked files.

Comment: similar to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1587846/how-do-i-show-the-changes-which-have-been-staged/1587877

Comment: @houtanb, `git status` shows you a diff. (It doesn't show you all staged files).

Answer (score 416, accepted):

The best way to do this is by running the command:

```
git diff --name-only --cached
```

When you check the manual you will likely find the following:

```
--name-only
    Show only names of changed files.
```

And on [the example](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#_examples) part of the manual:

```
git diff --cached
    Changes between the index and your current HEAD.
```

Combined together, you get the *changes between the index and your current HEAD* and *Show only names of changed files*.

`--staged` is also available as an alias for `--cached` above in more recent Git versions.

NB: This can be combined with [`--diff-filter`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#Documentation/git-diff.txt---diff-filterACDMRTUXB82308203) to [only show (filter) staged files that are added (`A`), modified (`M`) etc](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2299672).

```bash
git diff --name-only --cached --diff-filter=AM
```

Comment: This is really useful because it allows you to get a list of filenames that you can then (in my case) pipe to a linter in a pre-commit hook.

Comment: If you add files with `git add -N [files]`, this includes those too, even though they are not actually staged for commit yet.  As such, it isn't quite exactly what we want for a pre-commit hook.

Comment: re "***last commit***"; Misleading. Better to say `git diff --cached` is short for `git diff --cached head`

Comment: This is great.  How can I get it to display the paths relative to my current working directory instead of relative to the root directory of the repository?

Comment: Most of the time, you would remove deleted files from the list because you're passing this file list to a command that expects that all files exist. To remove deleted files from the list, you could do : `git --no-pager diff --name-only --cached --diff-filter=AM`.

Comment: @pyrsmk great point, and it can also be interesting for only added `--diff-filer=A`. I added this to the answer. Also, since you write `--no-pager` you may be interested in `git diff-index` which I suspect is more of a plumbing command

Comment: I'd suggest using `--diff-filter=d` to only ignore deleted files, as you have renames and stuff in there you should be considering as well.

Comment: @Pistos With git 2.34.1 files added with -N are not listed. Perhaps this has been fixed since your comment?

Comment: I'm not sure when this occurred, but the pager seems to be used by default on macOS. Providing `-P` or `--no-pager` directly after `git` will resolve this. Does it make sense to update the main question? Or do other platforms treat this different?

Answer (score -8):

You can try using `git ls-files -s`

Comment: This seems to list ***all tracked*** files (staged or or unstaged), not the ***staged*** files (that the question is about). This does not answer the question: *"to see all the files I have staged ... without ... changed but unstaged files."*). This answer is blatantly wrong. Why is this being voted up when it doesn't answer the question (it answers some other question)?

Comment: This does ***not*** answer the question and is completely wrong. It answers some other question. Can you delete it, please? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Amplifying information: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28159325/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-different-fields-in-the-output-of-git-ls-files-s

Comment: that's doesn't do what is asked in the questions.

Comment: But anyway it sounds logical. What do I need? List files! What do I use? "ls-files". What do I need? Staged files! What do I use? "-s". Also "-s" is "--stage" git help. So it is git's fault.